# DragNDrop List View crashing in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm hoping it's somewhat obvious. I tried changing everything back to regular "listView" (rather than using the DragNDragList Library) and it still crashes.

I tried replacing these things with some generic example resources but I still get a crash.
I feel that there is something basic I'm overlooking that about the ListViewCursorAdaptor that is causing that crash, and that my problem isn't exclusive to the dragNdrop library.

can the problem have something to do with it being in a fragment?

My onCreateView:

```
myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_fragment, container, false);
    db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    db.open();
    Cursor TaskCursor = db.getAllTasks();

    list = (DragNDropListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dragList);

    Log.d("cursor", TaskCursor.getString(1)); //This shows me that my cursor obviously isn't empty

    adapter = new DragNDropCursorAdapter(myFragmentView.getContext(),
                               R.layout.task_list_item,
                               TaskCursor,
                               new String[]{DBAdapter.COLUMN_NAME},
                               new int[]{R.id.TaskItemTitle},
                               R.id.DragHandle);

    Log.d("apater", "test");

    list.setDragNDropAdapter(adapter); //Line 46 (where it crashes)

    Log.d("apater", "test");

    db.close();

    return myFragmentView;
```

My list fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.terlici.dragndroplist.DragNDropListView
    android:id="@+id/dragList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    /></LinearLayout>
```

My List Item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/DragHandle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/drag_handle" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TaskItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/card_text" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textSize="8sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Library: https://github.com/terlici/DragNDropList

And the LogCa:

```
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575): Process: edu.jcu.cs470.togenda, PID: 29575
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at edu.jcu.cs470.togenda.ToDoFragment.onCreateView(ToDoFragment.java:46)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5024)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:133)
05-05 12:16:19.456: E/AndroidRuntime(29575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 12:17:01.898: I/Process(29575): Sending signal. PID: 29575 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you log say its a null point exception and its in listview.please try to replace

```
 list = (DragNDropListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dragList);
```

to

```
 list = (DragNDropListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.dragList);
```

You are using  **getactivity()** please using your inflate view name in your case its is **myFragmentView** that why a null point excetin is occuring.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move below code to onViewCreated(). My guess is findViewById is returning null because view is still being created.

```
db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    db.open();
    Cursor TaskCursor = db.getAllTasks();

    list = (DragNDropListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dragList);

    Log.d("cursor", TaskCursor.getString(1)); //This shows me that my cursor obviously isn't empty

    adapter = new DragNDropCursorAdapter(myFragmentView.getContext(),
                               R.layout.task_list_item,
                               TaskCursor,
                               new String[]{DBAdapter.COLUMN_NAME},
                               new int[]{R.id.TaskItemTitle},
                               R.id.DragHandle);

    Log.d("apater", "test");

    list.setDragNDropAdapter(adapter); //Line 46 (where it crashes)

    Log.d("apater", "test");

    db.close();
```

and replace

```
list = (DragNDropListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dragList);
```

by

```
list = (DragNDropListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dragList);
```